# How do I store playframework database configuration on the tomcat classpath?

Tags: playframework, tomcat7, playframework-2.1

I'm using playframework 2.10 and use play2war plugin to deploy it to tomcat.

I don't like the way play framework stores database configuration properties in application.conf. It doesn't seem easy to move the application to another machine or change database configuration in different modes.

I'm looking for a way to store database configuration in tomcat properties class path, catalina.properties for example.